# Bind value of Foreign Key to Datagrid (WPF / EF)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

This will be my first project with MVVM and EF..
I have seen some answers, but it is still not clear to me.

I generated an EF model from a Database. In this database :

1) table Crew with property RankId as foreign key to table Rank

2) table Rank

In my CrewListView is a datagrid populated with List

How can I get the name of the Rank in this datagrid instead of the Id??

View:

```
            <--This does (offcourse) not work -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rank" Binding="{Binding RankName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:
        private IList _crew;

```
    public IList<Crew> AllCrew
    {
        get
        {
            if (_crew == null)
            {
                GetCrew();
            }
            return _crew;
        }
    }

    private void GetCrew()
    {
        using (var crewrepo = new CrewRepository())
        {
            _crew = crewrepo.GetAll();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please share some relevant code. eg. what is binded to datagrid, what are available properties etc.

Comment: Crew and Rank are POCO's

Comment: Does your Crew class have a navigation property of type Rank? If not, I'd suggest you add one. Then you can use the .Include extension method to load the Rank object associated with the Crew object through your foreign key and bind to the name with Binding="{Binding Rank.RankName}".

Answer (score 0):

.Include did the trick

Using System.Data.Entity

CrewRepository
dbSet.Include("Rank");

View: